# Setting state results in TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have the following error on line 20 where the state is set for `showNoResultsMessage`

```
TypeError: this is undefined
```

I think this may be due to an issue with the context that 'this' is called. However, I'm not sure how to get around the issue or what `this` is in this instance when it is setting the state. I'm guessing it's empty and needs to be passed through somehow.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class MainApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        this.getLocation();
    }

    getPlaces(position) {
        const mainDiv = document.querySelector("#main-app");
        const mapTag = mainDiv.getAttribute('data-map');
        let apiUrl = "https://example.com/places.json";

        const url = apiUrl + "?lat=" + position.coords.longitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.latitude + "&tags=" + mapTag;

        console.log("mapag: " + mapTag);
        console.log("url: " + url);
        this.setState({showNoResultsMessage: true});
    };

    /**
     *  Could not get location, present error message
     */
    locationErrorHandler(err) {
        if (err.code == 1) {
            alert("Error: Access is denied!");
        } else if (err.code == 2) {
            alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * First attempts to get location and from there, runs the api call to get places.
     */
    getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
            var options = {timeout: 60000};
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getPlaces, this.locationErrorHandler, options);
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Get Started</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MainApp/>,
    document.getElementById('main-app')
)
```

Comment: bind `getPlaces` (and `getLocation`) in constructor or use arrow syntax in method declarations

Comment: Where are you running `getPlaces`? is `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` running it as a callback?

Comment: Let me know if this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717480/2482274) solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your inner functions in constructor. Update your constructor code by below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showNoResultsMessage: false 
    }
    this.getPlaces = this.getPlaces.bind(this);
    this.locationErrorHandler = this.locationErrorHandler.bind(this);
    this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
}
```

I also observed you are setting state in a function but not initializing it. Have added state too in the constructor. You can change its value as per your requirement.

Comment: Many thanks Divyang, looks like initializing the state and binding it resolved the issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the functions in your constructor like this:

```
this.getLocation.bind(this);
```

or use arrow function syntax like this:

```
 getLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
        var options = {timeout: 60000};
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getPlaces, this.locationErrorHandler, options);
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
    }
}
```